# Testing Pointers for NULL and Comparing Dereferenced Values

Tags: c++, pointers, null, comparison, dereference

I want to know if there is a C++ function, or at least a convention for doing this:

```
int a = 5, b = 5, *pa = &a, *pb = &b; //These are example values if the if statement were true

if( ( pa == NULL && pb == NULL ) || ( pa != NULL && pb != NULL && *pa == *pb ) ) //Do stuff
```

I can improve on this a little by doing: `!( ( pa == NULL ) ^ ( pb == NULL ) ) && ( !pa || *pa == *pb )`
But it just seems like there should be a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: What do you want to happen if one pointer is null but the other isn't?

Comment: They aren't equal values so the condition should be false.

Comment: There's not a better way :( Perl has a great syntax `pa // NULL == pb // NULL` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably write:

```
if (pa == pb || (pa && pb && *pa == *pb))
```

You could get the benefit of that Perl syntax with a function template backed by a helper class that implements comparison:

```
template <typename T>
struct Maybe {
    T *ptr
    explicit Maybe(T *ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    bool operator==(const Maybe &other) const {
        return (ptr == other.ptr) || (ptr && other.ptr && *ptr == *other.ptr);
        // or whatever other answer to this question you like
    }
    bool operator!=(const Maybe &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};

// could make it work for smart pointer types too,
// but this is simple
template <typename T>
Maybe<T> maybe(T *ptr) { return Maybe<T>(ptr); }

if (maybe(pa) == maybe(pb)) ...
```

Obviously that's only worth if it you do this in a lot of different places. And to replace this one use of the Perl syntax, you could just as well have a function template that takes two pointers and returns the result...

Comment: What if `operator*` is overloaded to return a random value? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: you can't overload operators on `int*` ;-) Given that the questioner proposes an alternative involving `^` I think I'm safe from operator overloads, but it may be worth noting that this isn't equivalent in the case of `float` because of NaNs.

Comment: @Steve Jessop I hope that your answer and the xor would be binary-equivalent. I did recognize that my original answer had a flaw `!( pa ^ pb ) && ( !pa || *pa == *pb )` because `^` does not correctly handle if `pa = 0x01234567` and `pb = 0xFEDCBA98` because it's a _bitwise_ operator. So mine had to be changed to: `!( ( pa == NULL ) ^ ( pb == NULL ) ) && ( !pa || *pa == *pb )` All that to say yours just looks cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

One possible simplification is:

```
if ( ( pa == pb ) || ( pa != NULL && pb != NULL && *pa == *pb ) ) //Do stuff
```

This works because the first clause handles two cases: (i) both `pa` and `pb` are `NULL` or (ii) `pa` and `pb` are not NULL, but they are equal and therefore point to the same value, in which case `*pa == *pb`.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate "either both pointers are null, or both pointers are non-null and the pointees are equal", could be written like this:

```
return pa == NULL ? pb == NULL : (pb != NULL && *pa == *pb);
```

Comment: Generally the rule is logical operators are faster than conditional operators. So I'm trying to stay away from something like this.

Comment: @JonathanMee: whose rule is that?

Comment: @JonathanMee: That rule definitely has to go on my list.

Comment: @Steve Jessop I thought that was common knowledge. But I just timed it and `if( pa == NULL ? pb == NULL : (pb != NULL && *pa == *pb)` is far slower than `if (pa == pb || (pa && pb && *pa == *pb))` when a and b are random, and where pa and pb are randomly NULL or pointing toward their respective values.

Comment: @JonathanMee: That may not be a fair comparison of the logical vs. conditional operators, since using `pa == pb` in effect optimizes for the case where `pa` and `pb` are frequently null (and hence equal) as in that case it short-circuits after a single test. What about Kerrek's code against what you started with, `( pa == NULL && pb == NULL ) || ( pa != NULL && pb != NULL && *pa == *pb )`? Or my code against `(pa == pb) ? true : (pa && pb && *pa == *pb)`.

Comment: Notice that the ternary also short circuits if both are NULL. I think the reason that the conditional is slower is because in the assembly you've introduced an additional jump command, and whenever branch prediction gets that wrong, it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

> if (pa == pb || pa && pb && *pa == *pb) // Do stuff